# Is there any advantage using separate domain for mails?

Tags: email

Even if Facebook can use `facebook.com` or `mail.facebook.com`, Facebook uses `facebookmail.com` for sending notifications, etc.

Basically it is bad practice since users may think that it is a spam message... It affects Facebook. But companies like Facebook don't do such things without having a reason.

So, I want to know, is there any advantage using separate domain for mails?

Comment: `@facebookmail.com` addresses can be used by anybody.  I'm sure Facebook using `@facebook.com` for their employees.  Same with Google.  They use `@google.com` but the public can sign up for `@gmail.com`

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I understand what you said. But my question different. Google never send official mails like notifications from gmail.com. They always use email address like no-reply@google.com, etc.But Facebook send official mails by <notification+fgfgfgf3434@facebookmail.com. Why is that? I mean according to me, it is really bad practice.

Comment: Can't you reply to the Facebook notification to reply to the Facebook conversation?   If so then the address is being used more like a user registered address than a strict notification from company address.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I am not sure about it, but I believe I can't.

Comment: It also occurs to me that Facebook is big enough that it can do what it wants.   Anybody filtering mail pretty much has to let FB mail through or users will get upset quickly.   That isn't going to be the case for smaller sites sending notifications.

Answer (score 10):

One purpose is to help protect domains from incidental spam. A good practice by many large companies that have emails generated by users (either directly or via actions taken online) is to have the emails send through a completely different domain, generally from a different IP range to that of your main servers. In this way someone flagging emails as spam when they come from `@facebookmail.com` doesn't impact on emails sent from `@facebook.com`. This is just one aspect of it of course, but would be one of the higher up reasons for consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Using a different domain to send your email may be a way to avoid your main domain being blocked for spam.  This might especially be true if you have users who send email through your domain (like the Google example above), but it can happen in other situations as well.